# Android RemoteControlClient always shows "Unknown Artist" on htc one

Tags: android, audio, android-service, lockscreen, htc-android

We are trying to set metadata on the RemoteControlClient (lockscreen) when playing music from a service. This works fine on most phones/emulators, but we cannot seem to populate the "artist" field on an htc one (possibly other htc sense based phones as well). Title and artwork populate fine. We are trying any relevant fields we can think of:

```
client.editMetadata(true)
            .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST, track.getArtist())
            .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_AUTHOR, track.getArtist())
            .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_WRITER, track.getArtist())
            .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_COMPOSER, track.getArtist())
            .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, track.getArtist())
```

None of these work. Anyone had experience with this?